# Access variable outside foreach loop PHP

Tags: php, variables, magento, foreach

I'm new to PHP. Can anyone tell me how to access the foreach loop variable outside foreach. Please find below by code.

```
  <?php  $categories = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->getCollection()->addAttributeToSelect('*'); 
         foreach ($categories as $category): 
         $categorySize = $category->getSize_chart(); 
         print_r ($categorySize); 
         endforeach;
    ?>
```

I need it in the following html img tag's src attribute.

```
<div class="SizeChat"><p>close</p><div class="Padd"><img src="<?php echo Mage::getBaseUrl('media').'catalog/category/'.$categorySize ?>"></div></div>
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

First define the variable above of the loop

```
$categorySize = array();

<?php  $categories = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->getCollection()->addAttributeToSelect('*'); 
         foreach ($categories as $category): 
         $categorySize = $category->getSize_chart(); 
         print_r ($categorySize); 
         endforeach;
    ?>

print_r($categorySize) //Now you can get it outside the loop
```

Comment: Thank you. Can you please explain me the changes you have made.

Comment: @Swetha your categorySize var scope within the loop that why you can't get it ouside and i was defined at outside the loop, now the variable scope it also available outside the loop

Comment: Thank you for explaining it :)