# how to get all the xml data outside foreach or how to declare this foreach inside the xml

Tags: php, arrays, xml, simplexml

```
   foreach($items as $item => $values) {
   $_product =  wc_get_product( $values['data']->get_id()); 
    $quantity = $values['quantity'];
        $length =  $_product->get_length(); 
    $width  =  $_product->get_width();  
        $height =  $_product->get_height();     

    if(($_product->get_weight()) && ($values['quantity'])){
           $weight = $_product->get_weight() *  $values['quantity'];
    }else{
        $weight = $_product->get_weight();
     } 

 $test_array = array (
'PackageType' => 'ITEM',
'Items' => $quantity,
'TotalKgs' => $weight,
'TotalCubic' => '0',
'Length' => $length,
'Width' => $width,
'Height' => $height,    
);

$xml_data1 = array_to_xml($test_array, new SimpleXMLElement('<LineItem/>'));
$dom = dom_import_simplexml($xml_data1);
$xml_data = $dom->ownerDocument->saveXML($dom->ownerDocument->documentElement);
//print_r( $xml_data);
$testing = htmlentities($xml_data);
$testing1 =html_entity_decode($testing);
echo    $testing1;
 }
```

I need all the xml datas from $testing1 out side the foreach in the variable 
to pass on the xml 
I need all the xml datas from $testing1 out side the foreach in the variable 
to pass on the xml

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Access variable outside foreach loop PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32794570/access-variable-outside-foreach-loop-php)

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you declare Global Variables such as `$globalXML = "";` and then, inside the `foreach` loop, simply run at the end `$globalXML .= $testing1;`?

In this way, it'll keep adding the parsed XML one by one to the Global Variable until the `foreach` is finished running.

Besides, you'll be able to use the `$globalXML` variable anywhere within the document!

Hope that helps!!

Comment: only last value get print if i declare as global variable also

Comment: @Vivek There, I fixed the answer, does it work for you?

Comment: @Vivek Sorry, I used JavaScript for a moment there, my bad!

Comment: when i get the value outside the foreach loop its showing only the last data. if i declared as global too its showing oly the last data

Comment: @Vivek If you add the Values one by one using `.=` to the Global Variable, it should work.

Comment: <lineitem>
<packagetype>ITEM</packagetype>
<items>117</items>
<totalkgs>70</totalkgs>
<totalcubic>0</totalcubic>
<length>44</length>
<width>55</width>
<height>66</height></lineitem>

all the values combined for eg i need height as <height>6</height><height>6</height> but its showing as <height>66</height>